# Azure - Linux Standard B2ms - Turned off automatically?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Linux Standard B2ms azure virtual machine. I have disabled the autoshutdown feature you see in your dashboard under operations. For some reason this server was still shutdown after running about 8 days.

What reasons are there which could shutdown this server if I haven't changed anything on it the last three days?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> What reasons are there which could shutdown this server if I haven't
>   changed anything on it the last three days?

There are many reasons will shutdown this VM, maybe we should try to find some logs about this.

First, we should check Azure `Alerts` via Azure portal, try to find some logs about you VM.

Second, we should check this VM's performance, maybe high CPU usage or high memory usage, we can find logs in `/var/log/*`.

Also we can try to find are there some issue about Azure service, we can check `service Health` -> `Health history` to find are there some issues in your region.
[image]

By the way, if we just create one VM in Azure, we can't avoid **a single point of failure.** In Azure, Microsoft **recommended** that two or more VMs are created within an availability set to provide for a highly available application and to meet the 99.95% Azure SLA.

An **availability set** is composed of two additional groupings that protect against hardware failures and allow updates to safely be applied - **fault domains** (FDs) and **update domains** (UDs).

**Fault domains**:

A fault domain is a logical group of underlying hardware that share a common power source and network switch, similar to a rack within an on-premises datacenter. As you create VMs within an availability set, the Azure platform automatically distributes your VMs across these fault domains. This approach limits the impact of potential physical hardware failures, network outages, or power interruptions.

**Update domains**:

An update domain is a logical group of underlying hardware that can undergo maintenance or be rebooted at the same time. As you create VMs within an availability set, the Azure platform automatically distributes your VMs across these update domains. This approach ensures that at least one instance of your application always remains running as the Azure platform undergoes periodic maintenance. The order of update domains being rebooted may not proceed sequentially during planned maintenance, but only one update domain is rebooted at a time.

In your scenario, maybe there are some **unplanned maintenance events**,when Microsoft update the VM host, they will migrate your VM to another host, they will shutdown your VM then migrate it.

To achieve a highly available, maybe we should create at least two VMs in one availability set.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I can go with this for now. So things I would say are in my opinion strange, like unplanned maintenance shuts down a vm. I have a different vm somewhere else which is always up and they also do maintenance, but lets not start that discussion. I'll check the logs and such. This isn't doubled for it's a development machine. Strangely my other vm was also down (same resource group), so I'll also check the credits.